# TypeScript class with same name as interface

Tags: typescript

I'd like to declare a class called `Date` which has a property of type Date (as in the TypeScript interface to the JavaScript [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). However the compiler assumes my property is of the same type as the class I'm declaring. How can I distinguish between the two?

If the Date interface were in a module I could just use the module name to distinguish, however it seems to be in a global namespace. My `Date` class is inside a module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is no special keyword to access the global namespace, but the following works:

```
// Create alias (reference) to the global Date object
var OriginalDate = Date;

// Make copy of global Date interface
interface OriginalDate extends Date {}

module Foo {
    export class Date {
        public d: OriginalDate; // <-- use alias of interface here
        constructor() {
            this.d = new OriginalDate(2014, 1, 1); // <-- and reference to object here
        }
    }
}

var bar = new Foo.Date();
alert(bar.d.getFullYear().toString());
```

See also: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/core.d.ts

In the past, I've always named such classes "DateTime" to avoid this problem (and possible confusion).

Comment: Are you sure this works ? In my TypeScript I can't distinguish like this between the NameSpace Name and my Class.

ps. the link does not work