# TypeScript definition : same name but different types inside and outside module?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to build the typescript definition file for this code (in `myscript.ts`) :

```
var rectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(20, 20), new Size(60, 60));
var path = new Path.Rectangle(rectangle);
path.strokeColor = 'black';
```

Please note that here first Rectangle is a different type from the second (`Path.Rectangle`).

This is what I have for now (in `myscript.d.ts`) :

```
declare class Point {
    constructor(x: number, y: number);
    add: (something: number[]) => Point;
}
declare class Size {
    constructor(width: number, height: number);
}
declare class Rectangle {
    constructor(point: Point, size: Size);
    topLeft: Point;
    bottomRight: Point;
}
declare module Path {
    class PathBase {
        strokeColor: string;
        bounds: Rectangle; // <== here I need the Rectangle type defined outside of the Path module
        fillColor: Color;
    }

    export class Rectangle extends PathBase {
        constructor(point: Point, size: Size);
        constructor(rec : Rectangle); // <== here I need the Rectangle type defined outside of the Path module
    }
}
```

With this definition, both of the following lines failed :

```
var path = new Path.Rectangle(rectangle);
var upperLeft = path.bounds.topLeft;
```

I understand why but don't know how to fix the definition. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If I were you I'd change the name, not sure there's any other solution.

Comment: @Omri : I can't change the name, as the code is from an external lib : paperjs. In fact the raw code is from here : http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#path-rectangle-rectangle

Comment: Probably there is no easy and nice way, but you should be able to workaround it by declaring a fake name alias (e.g. `declare interface __r extends Rectangle {}` and using the alias `__r` instead of the global scope `Rectangle`, similar to the way used in [Stack Overflow: TypeScript class with same name as interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591245/typescript-class-with-same-name-as-interface)

Comment: @xmojmr based on your comment, I found a valid definition, see below. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

Based on @xmojmr comment, I found a valid definition :

My first attempt :

```
declare class Rectangle {
    constructor(point: Point, size: Size);
    topLeft: Point;
    bottomRight: Point;
}
```

becomes :

```
declare class NumericRectangle { // <=================== renamed
    constructor(point: Point, size: Size);
    topLeft: Point;
    bottomRight: Point;
}

declare class Rectangle extends NumericRectangle {  // <=================== added
}
```

... and

```
declare module Path {
    class PathBase {
        strokeColor: string;
        bounds: Rectangle; // <== here I need the Rectangle type defined outside of the Path module
        fillColor: Color;
    }

    export class Rectangle extends PathBase {
        constructor(point: Point, size: Size);
        constructor(rec : Rectangle); // <== here I need the Rectangle type defined outside of the Path module
    }
}
```

... becomes :

```
declare module Path {
    class PathBase {
        strokeColor: string;
        bounds: NumericRectangle;  // <=================== modified
        fillColor: Color;
    }

    export class Rectangle extends PathBase {
        constructor(point: Point, size: Size);
        constructor(rec: NumericRectangle); // <=================== modified
    }
}
```